# run_console oauth flow does't exist as the documentation suggests?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, google-cloud-shell

I try to run oauth flow code in python on a google-cloud shell.

[image]

But I get an error as the method "run_console" doesn't exist. How can it be?

[image]

Comment: Please edit  your question and include your code not images of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**run_console** was deprecated don't use that method

> New clients will be unable to use `InstalledAppFlow.run_console` starting on Feb 28, 2022. All clients will be unable to use this method starting on Oct 3, 2022. Use `InstalledAppFlow.run_local_server` instead. For details on the OOB flow deprecation, see https://developers.googleblog.com/2022/02/making-oauth-flows-safer.html?m=1#disallowed-oob

use **run_local_server** for installed applications.

```
def build_service(credentials, scope, user_token):
    creds = None

    if os.path.exists(user_token):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(user_token, scope)

    # If there are no (valid) user credentials available, prompt the user to log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                credentials, scope)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open(user_token, 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())
    try:
        return build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - any errors returned.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')
```